# Best way to serve media files stored in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a podcast application which allows users to upload and play their own audio podcast.

I am planning to store the audios on AWS S3. For some reasons, I need to have a permanent like to each of the audios such as: `https://mywebsite.com/podcasts/1/audios/3.mp3`.

I know the AWS SDK allows me to create pre-signed URLs for download but they expire after a certain time, so I have made an endpoint on my API which creates pre-signed URL on the fly and redirects the client to the generated URL (with an HTTP 3XX code).

The workflow:

> client requests endpoint `/podcasts/1/audios/3/audio` -> API generates a pre-signed
> URL for audio 3 of podcast 1 -> API redirects client to the
> pre-signed URL with a HTTP 3XX code -> client downloads the audio

It is working fine but I have strong doubts it is the best way to proceed as 1) the URI doesn't have the .mp3 extension, and 2) I think it is a heavy process to generate pre-signed URL all the time.

Could someone give me their opinion on this ?
Or could someone tell me what is the "standard" way to create a permanent link to an audio file using S3 or any other service ?

Comment: Do you some extra access controls for those podcasts? The normal way is to just put a cloudfront in front of the bucket which handles caching and global distribution and be done with it.

Comment: If you use a Streaming API such as https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-reactive-api, you can build a solution that reads content from an S3 bucket and render it to the browser. Taking this app further, you can build the site to require users to login via Cognito if you prefer such functionality. And you are correct - you do not want to keep using pre-sign functionality so you content is available. Working on a Java based example that renders media (MP4) to release soon.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from adding a .mp3 extension to your API endpoint. Also, generation of pre-signed URLs is very lightweight, it doesn't even make a call to AWS to create them, so that shouldn't be an issue.